# Apache STORM - Tuples Distribution among workers

Tags: grouping, apache-storm, shuffle

I am working on a project using Apache STORM and the topology that I'm using consist of Spout, BoltA(2 Executors) and BoltB(1 Executor) in sequence.

```
                                      Spout --> BoltA --> BoltB
```

My understanding is that Shuffle grouping divide the tuples equally among the bolt tasks but what I noticed is that it is true only when all the tasks are on the same worker. When there are more than 1 workers let's say 2 workers and each worker hosts one task instance of same bolt then load is not even in both the tasks.

With my topology - I have load on one task as 90% and the second task has 0%.

Why is that different for multiple workers.

Comment: Storm version that I am using is 2.0.1

Comment: Are you using regular shuffle grouping, or local or shuffle grouping?

Answer (score 0):

If you have shuffle connections between the Spout and BoltA, the tuples should be evenly distributed.

As Stig Rohde Døssing mentioned, the behavior you mention matches the "local or shuffle grouping" (see [Storm Concepts](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Concepts.html)) which will preferentially send tuples to tasks on the local worker process.

So if the Spout has a parallelism of 1 and one of the BoltA tasks is on the same worker process, tuples from the spout will be preferentially routed to that local downstream task.